# Copy and paste cell range while multiplying by a constant

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone explain to me why:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Integer, erow As Integer, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6) 
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
Next i

End Sub
```

Works fine, and I can see why. But, if I make

```
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
```

multiply by a constant:

```
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 6) * 2
```

I get a type mismatch error.

Comment: shot in the dark, try : `sheet2.Cells(erow, 1) = cdbl(sheet1.Cells(i, 6)) * 2`

Comment: No luck! Still gettin' that type mismatch error.

Comment: Also not sure if this is helpful but the formats of the cells I'm copying over range between General and Currency

Comment: have you tried `.Value2`?  `sheet2.Cells(erow, 1).value = cdbl(sheet1.Cells(i, 6).value2) * 2`

Comment: @ScottCraner still nothing!

Comment: What is entered in sheet1.cells(i,6)? Can you describe all variations, give examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm nearly positive, as much as I can be without seeing the actual data, that you're trying to multiply a non-numeric (something textual like `dog` in a cell).

You don't need to have any loop since only the `lastrow` variable is going to be used.

When your code errors click `Debug` and then select `sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 6)`. Copy that then paste it into the Immediate window (View>Immediate Window or Ctrl+G to bring it up in the IDE) immediately following a question mark like `?sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 6)`. Hit enter and you'll see what the value in the cell is. The `?` is shorthand for `Debug.Print`. This will evaluate the expression and show you what the cell contains. I'd also suggest using either `.Value` or `.Value2` since `Value` is the default member of `Range` that's accessed when nothing is specified. If you're interested https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim erow As Long
    erow = sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    sheet2.Cells(erow, 1) = sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 6) * 2
    sheet2.Cells(erow, 2) = sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 7)
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** I want to bring up that using `Dim sheet1 as Worksheet` is something that can cause conflict with a worksheets `CodeName` property, since it names them as `Sheet1, Sheet2, ... SheetN` by default. Potentially confusing if/when you use the worksheet CodeName to access worksheets.

Comment: Aha! Awesome. First off - thanks for the comment, really helpful information scattered throughout. Seems like I was bringing in the title of the numeric columns with i = 1, switched it to i = 2 and the multiplicative factor worked throughout the whole column!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Cell1Val As Integer
Dim Cell2Val As Integer

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
lastrow = 10

For i = 0 To lastrow

Cell1Val = Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
Cell2Val = Sheet2.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value

Sheet2.Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value = Cell1Val * 2

Next i
```

Here's the concept I use. Modify for you're application.